# OverridePendingTransition for Fragmentbased Preferenceactivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

In my currenct project I am using a custom animation to switch between activities which works fine.

But since this animations is used on every activity switch my fragment based [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) looks a little bit out of place.

I tried already to override the Transition in onBuildStartFragmentIntent (which for me seems to be the only indicator that a new activity will be started.

```
    @Override
    public Intent onBuildStartFragmentIntent (String fragmentName, Bundle args, int titleRes, int shortTitleRes) {
        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slideinleft, R.anim.slideoutleft);
        return super.onBuildStartFragmentIntent(fragmentName, args, titleRes, shortTitleRes);
    }
```

But this is not working.

**Edit:**
After Blundell's comment I read the question again I need to be more specific. It is actually not the PreferenceActivity itselfe where the overridePendingTransition is not working. When opening the PreferenceActivity form another Activiy it is working with a similar method like in Blundell's blog described.

What I meant was, when the PreferenceActivity is used on a small screns it has only one pane. When then a header is clicked a new Activity is openened. But all this behavior is handeled by the PreferenceActivity. If the header is clicked and the PreferenceActivity opens a new Activity, I would like to open this new screen with a custom animation.

Comment: You should be doing it onCreate before setContentView: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/animate-an-activity/ If this isn't the case add more detail to your question to explain what you've tried.

Comment: The method in your Blog is known to me (Actually this is what I am using for the normal activities). But when using a PreferenceActivity change the fragment (dual pane view) or open a new activity is handeled by the preference Activity (you only provide the headers as XML and the Fragments). So there is no explicit Activity where you can override the onCreate method to put the .overridePendingTransionio(...).

Answer (score 1):

In documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onBuildStartFragmentIntent(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, int, int))
method

```
Intent onBuildStartFragmentIntent (String fragmentName, 
            Bundle args, 
            int titleRes, 
            int shortTitleRes)
```

is described:

> Called by startWithFragment(String, Bundle, Fragment, int, int, int) when in single-pane mode, to build an Intent to launch a new activity showing the selected fragment. The default implementation constructs an Intent that **re-launches** the current activity with the appropriate arguments to display the fragment.

So that explains that "weird" behavior. You can try this. In PreferenceActivity override method like this. That triggers custom animation for every fragment switch.

```
@Override
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);

    //return true value for valid fragments 

    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}
```

Of course, back animation you set separately.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

This code is from Preference Activity template.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);//Make the most sense
```

Otherwise try these?

```
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state);
onNewIntent(Intent intent);
```

Or override them all and do some logging

```
Log.d("Debug", "onCreate called");
```